# How can I play a video on a surface again after drawing black on it?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have a video player that gets reset and loaded with a new video in one activity. One of the problems I had with this approach was that the last frame of the previous window was still shown when the next video is loaded. Several people have the same issue.

I solved this by doing the following in the `onCompletion` listener, similar to what is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907818/435093) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660994/clear-video-frame-from-surfaceview-on-video-complete):

```
mPlayer.stop();
mPlayer.release();
Canvas canvas = mPlayView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
mPlayView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
mPlayer = null;
```

Then later, I call this again:

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
mPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
mPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.prepare();
// wait for onPrepared callback and play
```

The problem is that the video play surface is still black—no video is shown anymore.

How do I "reset" the canvas and make it show the video again?

Or if that does not work, how do I clear the canvas of the last frame instead? I [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767742/android-videoview-clear-display-after-stopplayback) but the next loaded video still shows the last frame of the previous one.

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660994/clear-video-frame-from-surfaceview-on-video-complete explains why drawing on it with Canvas prevents the surface from being re-used, and has a pointer to a solution with OpenGL ES that should work.  (It works with MediaCodec, haven't tried it with MediaPlayer.)  Another solution is to create a new opaque black View on top of the player, and show/hide it.